# Relation aggregate filter for displaying pictures

Tags: qgis, atlas, 1tomany

In my QGIS atlas, I need to display 4 different pictures for each current feature.

My coverage layer is "features".
"features" is linked by a 1 to many relationship with my "photos" table

The "path" to each pictures is stored in a "path" field of my "photos" table

in my "photos" table, the field "atlas_photos" contains values from 1 to 4.

In my atlas :

- in my photo 1 rectangle, in the expression builder for the filepath I'm trying to get the "path" value in my "photos" table where "atlas_photos"='1' for the current atlas feature
- in my photo 2 rectangle, in the expression builder for the filepath I'm trying to get the "path" value in my "photos" table where "atlas_photos"='2' for the current atlas feature

and so on...

I tried to do this using a simple relation aggregate but there is no "filter" parameter.

if I  use `relation_aggregate('featurestophotosrelation',aggregate:='concatenate',expression:="path",concatenator:=';', order_by:="atlas_photos"='1')`

I don't understand the order of the results wich is not sorting the aggregate by 1, 2 ,3 and so on

Comment: `"atlas_photos"='1'` is likely returning `false` for all cases (`'1'` is a string an your values appear to be numeric), and is therefore nonsensical for sorting. You will likely have more success with `order_by:="atlas_photos"` which will yield a numeric value.

Comment: with "atlas_photos" as a int. using "atlas_photos"='1' or "atlas_photos"=1 or 2 or 3 doesnt change anything in the result. I always get the same order in the aggregate.

Comment: Use only `order_by:="atlas_photos`. Not `= 1` etc. When you use `= (something)` you get a boolean as the result of the expression. Using `order_by:="atlas_photos"` will yield the number itself that is associated with the current feature.

Comment: i actually solved it using "atlas_photo"='1'. This puts the desired value at the end of the aggregate. Thankfully my paths are the same lenght so i was able to right() the desired result. I repeated the same thing with "atlas_photo"='2', "atlas_photo"='3' and so on for the different photos rectangles.

Comment: I dont understand why i can't use concatenator and order by in the same relation_aggregate though.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing `order_by:=` and `filter:=`?

Comment: no. using QGIS 3.22.2. i use order_by:=. filter:= does not exist in relation_aggregate. it exists only in aggregate.